# Does javascript or nodejs has index range to access array item?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I saw this code in ruby

```
module Plutus
  TAX_RATES = {
    (0..18_200)                => { base_tax_amount:      0, tax_rate: 0 },
    (18_201..37_000)           => { base_tax_amount:      0, tax_rate: 0.19 },
    (37_001..80_000)           => { base_tax_amount:  3_572, tax_rate: 0.325 },
    (80_001..180_000)          => { base_tax_amount: 17_547, tax_rate: 0.37 },
    (180_001..Float::INFINITY) => { base_tax_amount: 54_547, tax_rate: 0.45 }
  }.freeze
end
```

It seems it is able to access an array item, when value is landing in range.

e.g. `given 18000`, is able to get `{base_tax_amount: 0, tax_rate: 0}`.

Is there any equivalent in javascript or nodejs?

Comment: Nope, there ain't any at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an array for the upper bounds and the objects as second element. Then you need a find function for the object.

```js
var TAX_RATES = [
        [18200, { base_tax_amount: 0, tax_rate: 0 }],
        [37000, { base_tax_amount: 0, tax_rate: 0.19 }],
        [80000, { base_tax_amount: 3572, tax_rate: 0.325 }],
        [180000, { base_tax_amount: 17547, tax_rate: 0.37 }],
        [Infinity, { base_tax_amount: 54547, tax_rate: 0.45 }]
    ],
    getTexRate = value => TAX_RATES.find(([v]) => value <= v)[1];

console.log(getTexRate(0));
console.log(getTexRate(10000));
console.log(getTexRate(20000));
console.log(getTexRate(100000));
console.log(getTexRate(1000000));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not that interface.
You have to recalculate index or use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```js
const TaxRates = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, prop) {
    switch (true) {
      case prop < 18200:  return { base_tax_amount: 0,     tax_rate: 0 };
      case prop < 37000:  return { base_tax_amount: 0,     tax_rate: 0.19 };
      case prop < 80000:  return { base_tax_amount: 3572,  tax_rate: 0.325 };
      case prop < 180000: return { base_tax_amount: 17547, tax_rate: 0.37 };
      default:            return { base_tax_amount: 54547, tax_rate: 0.45 };
    }    
  }
});

console.log([
  TaxRates[18000],
  TaxRates[35000],
  TaxRates[55000],
  TaxRates[550000],
]);
```